# Request working with Postman but with Angular returns 401

Tags: angular, .net-core, bearer-token

Here's my angular method

```
getGiftList(url: string){
let q = this.baseUrl + url;
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
let authToken = 'Bearer ' + this.authService.currentUser.token;

console.log(q); //Log the url ...
console.log(authToken); Log the token ...

headers.set('Authorization', authToken)

return this.http.get(q, {
  observe: 'response' 
  ,headers: headers
})
```

}

And this is the Asp.net core method

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class GiftController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("api/giftsByGiver/{email}")]        
    public IActionResult getGiftBasicRecordsByGiver(string email, int cpg = 1)
    {
       //
    }
}
```

When I make a request from my angular code, I get a `401` error. However, when I copy/peste the same values that I logged to Postman and run, I'm getting the right result.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for helping

Comment: have you checked whether you have an authorization header in postman? They can be hard to notice, you have to open the headers tab

Comment: @PaulDegnan, for the sake of the development and given that I'm still learning, I've set up policies to be allow any `origin, method, and header`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HttpHeaders is **immutable**. Calling set() doesn't mutate it. It returns a new instance of HttpHeaders. So you need

```
headers = headers.set('Authorization', authToken);
```

Or simpler, if you change the order of your instructions:

```
const authToken = 'Bearer ' + this.authService.currentUser.token;
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', authToken);
```

You should verify your assumptions: just open the network panel of your browser dev tools, and check if what you're sending is what you think you're sending.